# Python multiprocessing apply_async: can't pass list of lists as an argument?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, arguments

I am trying to use multiprocessing in Python. The following code

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(g):
    for i in g:
        print(i)

bubbles = [[1, 1], [2, 3], [6, 5]]
bubblesParts = np.array_split(bubbles, 2)

for part in bubblesParts:
    foo(part)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as p:
        for part in bubblesParts:
            print(part)
            p.apply_async(foo, args=(part)).get()
```

is giving me `TypeError: foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

At first I thought it's because maybe I can't use list of lists as an argument, but the first for loop showed me that I can.

Is apply_async function somehow trying to unpack the list part that is passed as an argument of foo? Or what else could be the problem?

Comment: I noticed that if I remove .get() the code executes without error, but print under multiprocessing doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you put a comma after `part` in your `apply_sync` call: `p.apply_async(foo, args=(part,)).get()`